# A 'To' phone number is required-- Twilio-- Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio

I'm new to Rails and this is the first time I'm implementing an API into my app. I'm creating an app that allows users to schedule text messages (SMS) with twilio. I'm trying to pass in 'number' so that the user can input the number. I've gotten the app to work when I hard code a number in but I'm getting "A 'To' phone number is required." when I try to pass in an argument.

Here's the controller

```
    class TextMessagesController < ApplicationController

      def index 
        @message = TextMessage.all
      end

      def new
        @message = TextMessage.new
      end

      def create 
        @active = 'messages'
        @message = TextMessage.send_sms(params[:number], params[:message])
        if @message.save
          flash[:success] = "Text Message Sent."
          redirect_to message_path
        else
          render 'home'
        end
      end

     def text_message_params
       params.require(:text_messages).permit(:number, :message)
     end
  end
```

Here's the Model

```
class TextMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

validates :message, length: { maximum: 160 }, presence: true

def self.send_sms(number, message)
  twilio_account_sid = 'XXXXXX'
  twilio_auth_token  = 'XXXXXX'
  twilio_number      = 'XXXXXX'

@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token

message = @client.account.sms.messages.create(
  :from => "+1#{twilio_number}",
  :to => "#{number}",
  :body => "#{message}"
  )
 end
```

end

Anyone know where I'm making my mistake?

Comment: I see an end after the last code block is it a part of the last code block ?

Comment: can you print `number` before trying to send the sms?

Comment: Just a side comment, but Twilio allows messages up to 1600 bytes in length - will be sent as a concatenated SMS and will be assembled on the user's handset! As for your code, I'm not entirely sure what the problem is - have you tried sending the SMS directly from your controller? Not that it matters, but it removes one extra layer that could get in the way...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `params[:number]` is blank:

```
@message = TextMessage.send_sms(params[:number], params[:message])
```

Maybe that should be `params[:text_messages][:number]` instead?  Basing this off of your `text_message_params` method (which you aren't taking advantage of).

```
@message = TextMessage.send_sms(params[:text_messages][:number], params[:text_messages][:message])
```

Answer (score 0):

you were absolutely right. Below is what I came up with. Thanks for you help!

```
    class TextMessagesController < ApplicationController

      def index 
        @message = TextMessage.all
      end

      def new
        @message = TextMessage.new
      end

      def create 
        @active = 'messages'
        @message = TextMessage.send_sms(text_message_params[:number], text_message_params[:message])
        if @message
          flash[:success] = "Text Message Sent."
          redirect_to text_messages_path
        else
          render 'home'
        end
     end

     def text_message_params
       params.require(:text_message).permit(:number, :message)
     end
   end
```